# TYPO3 v10.4.20 Class not found

Tags: typo3-10.x

**I upgraded TYPO3 from v9.5.31 to v10.4.20**
 **Backend works well but the Frontend I have the following error**

(1/1) Error

> Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Service\FlexFormService' not found

**Does anyone know why TYPO3 does not recognize the class?**

Thanks

Comment: What about https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.4/Deprecation-85802-MoveFlexFormServiceFromEXTextbaseToEXTcore.html?

Comment: Thanks, yes. Migration,
Use the new namespace to reference the TYPO3\CMS\Core\Service\FlexFormService.         The problem is I don't find where can I change the namespace! I'm new in Typo3 Cane you help me with an example please? Thank you.